# Google Cloud Endpoints: Transcoding messages with protobuf.Any fields

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

I have a grpc service that takes as input a message that contains fields of type protobuf.Any and I can't figure out the way to write correct json input for it. I am running on GKE, with cloud endpoint ESP and my service running in the same pod.

The protos look like:

```
message AnyArray {
    repeated google.protobuf.Any value = 1;
}
message Metric {
    string metric = 1;
    int64 timestamp = 2;
    double value = 3;
    map<string, AnyArray> metadata = 4;
}
```

I have tried multiple combinations for the input json with no luck, most of the times cloud endpoints returns "Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list." Failed examples:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "sample-key": {
            "value": [1, "one"]
        }
    },
    "metric": "request-count",
    "timestamp": 1528425789,
    "value": 0
}

{
    "metadata": {
        "sample-key": {
            "value": [{
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Duration",
                "value": "1.212s"
            }, {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Duration",
                "value": "1.212s"
            }]
        }
    },
    "metric": "request-count",
    "timestamp": 1528425789,
    "value": 0
}
```

Response from ESP

```
{
    "code": 3,
    "message": "metadata[0].value: Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.",
    "details": [{
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
        "stackEntries": [],
        "detail": "internal"
    }]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`google.protobuf.Any` means *any proto message type* so your first example doesn't work. For the second example, [google.protobuf.Duration](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/v3.6.0/src/google/protobuf/duration.proto) have a special JSON mapping, so following example should work:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "sample-key": {
            "value": [{
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Duration",
                "value": "1.212s"
            }, {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Duration",
                "value": "1.212s"
            }]
        }
    },
    "metric": "request-count",
    "timestamp": 1528425789,
    "value": 0
}
```

Note you will have to include all possible proto message types for the *google.protobuf.Any* in the proto descriptor set provided Cloud Endpoints service, otherwise it will fail to translate unknown types.

Another possible approach is use `google.protobuf.Struct` for your metadata, which eliminates the limitation above, but you will have to convert it to your expected types in your gRPC service.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried with the modification you provided and I still get the same error:
{
 "code": 3,
 "message": "metadata[0].value: Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.",
 "details": [
  {
   "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
   "stackEntries": [],
   "detail": "internal"
  }
 ]
}

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Also, although I use Any, my intention is to support only scalar types.

Comment: If you only want to support scalar types, then do not use `google.protobuf.Any`, just change `metadata` type to `google.protobuf.Struct`. Then first example you provided should work.

Answer (score 0):

Using protobuf.Struct instead of protobuf.Any solved my problem as @lizan recommended. Thanks!